# Existence of covers for outer measure $\mu^*$

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

In the proof of countable subaddivity of $\mu^*$ defined by $$\mu^*(E) = \inf\left\{\sum_{j=1}^\infty\rho(E_j): E_j \in \varepsilon, E \subset \cup_{j=1}^\infty E_j\right\}.$$
Let $$\mu^*(E_j) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\rho(E_j^k)$$ where 
$$E_j \subset \cup_{k=1}^\infty E_j^k \subset \varepsilon, E_j \notin \varepsilon$$

Since $\mu^*(E_j)$ is the $inf$ over possible coverings of $E_j$,
$$\sum_{k'=1}^\infty\rho(E_j^{k'}) \le  \mu^*(E_j) + \frac{\epsilon}{2^j}$$

I understand why we can write the inequality (call it *Ineq1*), based on the property of *inf* in $\mathbb{R}$.

I also get that there always exists at least one cover, the whole set $X \in \Large\varepsilon$. What guarantees the existence of any other cover that is neither $\cup_{k=1}^\infty E_j^k$ nor $X$? My understanding is that the existence of such covers depends on the elementary family $\Large\varepsilon$ on which $\rho$ is defined, irrespective of the property of $inf$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

What if $\Large\varepsilon$ is not rich enough, such that for some $j$ the possible covers of $E_j$ are only: $$\cup_{k=1}^\infty E_j^k \ or\ X$$ 
Then equality holds for the cover $\cup_{k=1}^\infty E_j^k$ and the only other cover is $X$ for $\epsilon > 0$.
If $$\frac{\epsilon}{2^j} \le \rho(X) - \mu^*(E_j) $$ then *Ineq1* is not satisfied. If we just use $\cup_{k=1}^\infty E_j^k$ as cover, we get $\epsilon \ge 0$.

What I am missing? In short, what guarantees the existence of covers that make the inequality hold for every $\epsilon > 0$?

Comment: [Outer measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure) are subadditive by definition, so you do not prove that they are subadditive. Are you talking about a step in the proof of the Caratheodory Extension Theorem?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist corrected formulation of question. In Folland, p. 29, Prop 1.10, "For each j, there exists $\{E_j^k\}_{k=1}^\infty \subset \varepsilon$ such that $A_j \subset \cup_{k=1}^\infty E_j^k$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \rho(E_j^k) \le \mu^*(A_j) + \epsilon2^{-j}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension of the measure $\rho:\mathcal{E}\to [0,\infty]$ to the power set of $X$, with $A\subset X$, is defined by

$$ \mu^*(A)=\inf \left\{ \sum_{j=1}^\infty \rho\left(E_j\right):E_j\in\mathcal E \text{ and } A\subset \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty E_j \right\} $$

Fix an $A \subset X$.

First, notice that the construction of the outer measure $\mu^*$ does not guarantee that you can find a collection of sets $\left\{ E_j \right\}_{j=1}^\infty$ (each of which is in $\mathcal E$, and whose union contains $A$) such that sum of the measures of these $E_j$'s attains the value $\mu^* (A)$. (To see this, think about the infimum of the set $(0,1)$.)

Thus, for any collection $\left\{E_j\right\}_{j=1}^\infty\subset\mathcal E$ such that $A\subset \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty E_j$, we can only guarantee that

$$ \mu^* (A) \leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty \rho\left(E_j\right) $$

where equality is not necessarily attained.

However, by the definition of the [infimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum#Properties), we should always be able to find some collection of $E_j$'s whose total measure (or, more precisely, sum of measures) is arbitrarily close to $\mu^* (A)$. If not, then $\mu^* (A)$ cannot be the greatest lower bound of the set defined above.

To be more specific, for any $\epsilon>0$, we can always find some collection $\left\{E_j^\epsilon \right\}_{j=1}^\infty$ such that

$$ \sum_{j=1}^\infty \rho\left(E_j^\epsilon\right) - \mu^*(A) \leq \epsilon $$

which is all you need for Folland 1.10.

Comment: All you wrote was already clear to me. 
However, in your  last paragraph, how does the property of _inf_ in $\mathbb{R}$ guarantee existence of such a cover, which depends on $\varepsilon$? 
Put another way, suppose $\mu^*(E_j) = \rho(A)$ where $E_j \subset A$ (proper subset) is one cover that achieves the _inf_.  What guarantees the existence of other covers $B$ such that $\rho(A) < \rho(B) < \rho(X)$? Note the strict inequalities here.

Comment: @P.M. Do you mean $A \subset E_j$? Nothing guarantees us being able to find an alternative cover whose measures add up to strictly more than the measure of $A$ but strictly less than the measure of $X$. Note however that Folland's proof of this step of the extension theorem does not rely on us being able to do so.

Comment: @P.M. To put this another way, if $\mathcal E$ is just the trivial $\sigma$-algebra $\{ \emptyset , X \}$, and $\rho$ is a measure on $\mathcal E$, then the extension $\mu^*$ as defined above would still be an outer measure.

Comment: I mean a cover $A \supset E_j, A \ne E_j$, not the $A$ in the answer. Ok, if we do not have such a guarantee, then how about the line I quoted from Folland, Prop 1.10? As I explained before, in case we have just two covers, we get $\epsilon = 0$, which it should not be, or some $\epsilon > 0$ where the inequality is not satisfied. Am I missing something?
To clarify, this is just a technical step in the proof of the countable subadditivity of $\mu^*$, in Prop 1.10 of Folland. By extension theorem, I guess you are referring to the Caratheodory Theorem.

Comment: @P.M. Yes, I am also referring to proposition 1.10 in Folland. Apologies, I prefer to think of 1.10 as just one part of the aforementioned extension theorem, which also includes theorem 1.11. That being said, 1.10 in Folland does not rely on being able to find this alternative cover. Think about the case where $\mathcal E$ is just the trivial ($\sigma$-)algebra, and notice that 1.10 applies to that as well.

Comment: @P.M. Added more detail to my answer above. What I added just follows from the property of $\inf$ I mention just before the addition.